# camera image getpixel colour for android app issue

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-camera, getpixel

Im pretty new to JAVA and this is my first stackoverflow post so I will try and be specific!

Well im trying to create an android application where the user can take a photo using the phones camera.the photo gets returned and placed with in an image view and the user can press a button to tell you what colour the image is. its working fine so far however I placed a picture of a green box within the image view for testing purposes and even tho the green box is being replaced with the new photo after you take a picture im still getting RGB values for the colour green despite the contents being replaced!

----my code----

```
private ImageView img;
private Bitmap bmp;
private Bitmap operation;
Button button;

ImageView imgFavorite;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imgFavorite = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imgFavorite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            open();
        }
    });

    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    BitmapDrawable abmp = (BitmapDrawable)img.getDrawable();
    bmp = abmp.getBitmap();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override`enter code here`
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pix();
        }
    });
}

public void open(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    imgFavorite.setImageBitmap(bp);
}

public void pix(){
    operation= Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(),
            bmp.getHeight(),bmp.getConfig());

    int height = bmp.getHeight();
    int width = bmp.getWidth();
    int p = bmp.getPixel(height / 2, width / 2);

    int r = Color.red(p);
    int g = Color.green(p);
    int b = Color.blue(p);

    Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(r) + String.valueOf(g) + String.valueOf(b), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}











@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: You may want to use a color other than green for testing the camera. YUV={0,0,0} is a medium green in RGB space, so an unmodified buffer can come back looking green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `onActivityResult()` you are setting the `ImageView` to display the new photo, but you are not setting the `bmp` variable, which is what you are using to read the RGB values. So just add this line to `onActivityResult()`:

```
bmp = bp;
```

Comment: RGB values are being returned, It was missing something so small, thank you very much!